# How do i avoid getting a list inside of a list

Tags: python, list, blackjack, card

I am making a blackjack simulator with python and are having problems with when the player want another card. To begin with the player gets a random sample of two numbers from a list and then get the option to take another card or not to. When the answer is yes another card is added to the random sample but it gets added as a list inside of the list.

This is is the line when the answer is yes to another card.

```
if svar == "JA":
    handspelare.append(random.sample(kortlek,1))
    print(handspelare)
```

This returns, [5, 10, [13]] and it is this list inside of the list i want to get rid of so i can sum the numbers, any suggestions on how i can get rid of this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`random.sample(kortlek,1)`

`random.sample` returns a list, so you end up `append`ing a list to `handspelare` (which creates the sublists).

You could change `append` to `extend`, but `random.sample(..., 1)` is just `random.choice`, so it makes more sense to use `handspelare.append(random.choice(kortlek))`.

Answer (score 1):

you should create a deck then shuffle it

```
deck = [52 cards]
deck.shuffle()
```

then just draw off it like a normal deck in the real world

```
hand.append(deck.pop())
if len(deck) < 15: # or something
   deck = [52 cards]
   deck.shuffle()
```

Comment: This is very presumptuous as to what OP is trying to achieve or to what other parts of OP's code look like.

Comment: i wouldnt say **very** ... a bit though ... 90+% of the time this pattern will serve well for "card games" ... your solution will return infinite duplicates potentially which this avoids (maybe the OP wants infinite duplicates)

Comment: How does this avoid the duplicates? `deck` is repopulated after `.pop`

Comment: representing a new "shoe" ... eventually you run out of cards ... in yours you could get 21 aces potentially (but i still was a +1 on yours as it does address OP's issue)

Answer (score -1):

Use list concatenation rather than append.

```
handspelare += random.sample(kortlek,1)
```

`append` will not unbundle its argument

```
a = [1]
a.append([2]) # [1, [2]]

a = [1]
a += [2] # [1, 2]
```